# Merge sales-tax and sales-taxes tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I noticed that we have both [sales-tax](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sales-tax) and [sales-taxes](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sales-taxes), both of which with a significant number of questions. (20 and 47, respectively, but only 7 questions with both.)

I propose that the two be merged into a single tag, preferably [sales-tax](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sales-tax).

Comment: No need for more discussion, done. Thanks, Michael.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer If you post that as an answer, I can accept it. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is so obvious there's no need for discussion, @JoeTaxpayer has done it already.